# XAMPP: Another web server is already running

Tags: apache, gitlab, lampp

I get the following error after installing gitlab..

```
root@Blase:~# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.9-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
[XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.][1]
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
```

I cannot access my localhost/phpmyadmin or any projects folder as am redirected to Gitlab.

I tried to view which program is using port 80 by running:
`"netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80"` and i got the output shown in attached image.
Any help guys?
[image]

Comment: Where is the attached image

Comment: nginx is already running on that port. GitLab uses nginx in an omnibus installation. Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I had to stop all the services,

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

$sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

$sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
```

Then I restarted the server

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 13):

**Running Server on Linux Ubuntu **

In my case Nginx server is already running that's why i am getting this kind of error.

I stop the Nginx Web server first then start Apache server.

**Stop Nginx server**

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

**Start Apache Server**

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

**Must Read**

Sometimes it can be port conflict between web servers. 
Changing the port number of both server or maybe one server we can run both servers at a time.

Answer (score 12):

I face this problem then I stop LAMP services.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

then check these services has stopped

```
sudo service apache2 status
sudo service mysql status
```

then run xammp and try start MySQL server and apache server

Answer (score 6):

The most possible reason why your Xampp server is not running is that you might have installed Xampp and apache2 simultaneously or MySQL server. So in order to work with Xampp server, you have to stop the Apache2 and MySQL.

`$sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

`$sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

And then restart Xampp server

```
$sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 3):

If when starting Apache server XAMPP responds "Another web server is already running", 
run this command: 
`sudo netstat -nap | grep :80`

you will see something like 
`tcp6       0      0 :::80         :::*  LISTEN      1078/apache2`

then run `sudo kill 1078` - in my case 1078 (in your case probably another number)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to stop Apache2

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

then you may restart lampp

```
$sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

[Link to pic of an illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rED0H.png)

Answer (score 1):

**sudo apachectl stop**
then starting apache web server from xampp manager worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. If I stop apache2 using:

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

the issue persists, refer to this site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/170640/how-to-disable-apache2-server-from-auto-starting-on-boot.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue using ubuntu 18.04, but all the solutions I found here did not solve my problem. So I want to share what I did so that it might help others as well.

go in the /etc folder in the root file system, and delete the Apache2 folder. Xampp has it's apache in the opt/lampp directory, so the Apache in the etc folder conflicts since this one starts at startup. To access these folders, use the command `$sudo nautilus`

Answer (score 0):

You can add convenient aliases to:

```
alias xampp-start='sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start'
alias xampp-stop='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop'
alias xampp-restart='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart'
alias xampp-gui='sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop && sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
```

Answer (score 0):

If still not resolved. please check [this link](https://medium.com/@kimiyukiyukawa/solved-xampp-another-web-server-is-already-running-66d90fb2a85e#).

It helped me.

This is the part that really solved my problem to stop the server that was running earlier.

> Solved by running this on terminal
>
> `sudo netstat -nap | grep :80`
>
> You’ll see apache2 and there is 3–4 digit numbers before it, mine is **980**
>
> `sudo kill [number]`
>
> where `[number]` is the number for `apache2`, in this case I run `sudo kill 980`
>
> *The number might be different than yours.
>
> Start XAMPP again.
>
> `cd /opt/lampp/ && sudo -s`
>
> `./lampp start`

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Execute comand `ps aux | grep mysql` in terminal and find the _mysql process from XAMPP. In my case:

   `_mysql            9092   0,0  0,4 34422708  61904 s000  S     9:39AM   0:03.23 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin/ --user=mysql --log-error=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MBP-Enrique.local.err --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MBP-Enrique.local.pid --socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3308`
2. Kill that process using its id: `sudo kill -9 [id]`. In my case: `sudo kill -9 9092`.
3. Restart XAMPP: `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp restart`.
4. All three servers start correctly this time.