# XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail. when running exampp in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, lampp

I got this error when I was running my xampp on my ubuntu

redha@redha:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
[sudo] password for redha: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.27-1... 
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail. 
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running. 
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378479/15770919)) solved my problem. For the purpose of this question, I shall re-iterate it.

Stop all services

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
```

Then restart the server
`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`